# How to fix 'Creating default object from empty value' warning in PHP

Tags: php, object, warnings

I get the following error from a joomla install that I have.

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in  /modules/mod_continuous_rss_scrolling/helper.php on line 54
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As it turns out, the author missed a very simple fix and general good practice that you should always initialize your object before you try to set a property. The very simple fix for this is simply to add a `new StdClass;` call right before the error with the variable it is trying to access.

```
$items[$i] = new StdClass;
$items[$i]->title   = $crs_post_title;
```

That first line will fix the warning from showing up.

This would also fix the problem in `/components/com_community/models/activities.php on line 387` with the following fix.

```
$commentsResult[$comment->type . '-' . $comment->contentid] = new StdClass;
$commentsResult[$comment->type . '-' . $comment->contentid]->_comment_count = 0;
```

Comment: If you don't know the whole code, is better to add a conditional to the creation line, because the warning could be circumstantial. For example:
if (!is_object($items[$i])) {$items[$i] = new stdClass;}
$items[$i]->title   = $crs_post_title;

Comment: You mean instantiate. Not initialize.

Comment: @Mark Tomlin I had a similar issue which is now solved