# Fixing 'Creating default object from empty value' warning in PHP

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, php-5.5

I recently uploaded a Joomla 2.5 site from my dev server to our host and discovered that one of the extensions that is a part of our site uses PHP code that is no longer "acceptable" in PHP 5.5. I keep getting the

> **Warning:** Creating default object from empty value .../helper.php on line 36

Since it is only one error I'm getting, I'd like to fix the php instead of simply hiding the warning.The relevant code line generating the error is:

```
$lists[$i]->id = $row->id;
```

I am aware that I should add a new `StdClass;` call right before the error with the variable it is trying to access per Mark Tomlin's response in this post [How to fix 'Creating default object from empty value' warning in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806959/how-to-fix-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-warning-in-php)

However, being a php newb I'm not sure how that would look in the code below.

```
{
public static function getList($params)
{

    $items = modArticlesLatestHelper::getList($params);

    $text_length = intval($params->get( 'preview_count', 200) );
    $tags       = $params->get('strip_tags', "a,i,br");

    $i=0;
    $lists  = array();
    foreach ( $items as $row )
    {
        //process content plugins
        $text = JHTML::_('content.prepare',$row->introtext);
        $lists[$i]->id = $row->id;
        $lists[$i]->thumb = self::getThumb($row->introtext,$params->get('thumb_width',160));
        $lists[$i]->created = $row->created;
        $lists[$i]->modified = $row->modified;
        $lists[$i]->link = $row->link;
        $lists[$i]->title = htmlspecialchars( $row->title );
        $lists[$i]->introtext = self::prepareContent( $text, $text_length, $tags);
        $i++;
    }

    return $lists;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions, ideas and help.

Comment: holy moly, I miss (not) seeing joomla code.

Comment: Should I have not posted so much code?

Comment: no it's good, I just never liked joomla code, and it looks like it hasn't improved that much after so many years. you should also turn off `display_errors` on production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create object before setting property

```
$lists[$i] = new stdClass();
$lists[$i]->id = $row->id;
```

Or single line solution

```
$lists[$i] = (object)array('id' => $row->id);
```

Comment: Thanks, about 30 seconds after I posted I tried that approach and it did the trick. Man, I feel pretty silly for not recognizing/trying it before posting. Thank you for your quick and accurate fix.