# error: {type: "ErrorException", message: "Creating default object from empty value"} in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

When I run the code given below I am getting the following error

> error: {type: "ErrorException", message: "Creating default object from
>   empty value"}

at this `$mandate->user_id = $current_user;` line.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806959/how-to-fix-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-warning-in-php) but still shows the same error. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
public function postProcess()
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $button_id = Input::get('button_id');
    $remarks = Input::get('remarks');
    $current_user = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    $mandate = new Mandate();
    $mandate = Mandate::find($id);

    $mandate->user_id = $current_user;
    $mandate->remarks = $remarks;

    $eventlog = new Eventlog();
    $eventlog->user_id = $current_user;
    $eventlog->mandate_id = $id;

    if($button_id == "reject"){
      $rejectreason_id = Input::get('rejectreason_id');
      $rejectreason = Input::get('rejectreason');
      $mandate->mandate_status = "Rejected";
      $mandate->rejectreason_id = $rejectreason_id;
      $eventlog->event = "Rejected: ".$rejectreason;   
    }else if($button_id == "verify") {
      $mandate->mandate_status = "Awaiting approval";
      $eventlog->event = "Verified";
    }
    else if($button_id == "approve") {
      $mandate->mandate_status = "Approved";
      $eventlog->event = "Approved";
    }

    $eventlog->save();
    $mandate->save();
    $this->generateXML($id,$rejectreason);
}
```

**EDIT 1** (As suggested by Suresh Kamrushi)

```
public function postProcess()
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $button_id = Input::get('button_id');
    $remarks = Input::get('remarks');
    $current_user = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    $rejectreason = "";
    $mandate = new Mandate();
    $mandate = Mandate::where('id',$id)->first();

    if(is_object($mandate)) {
      file_put_contents('log.txt', print_r("no mandate", true));
      $mandate->user_id = $current_user;
      $mandate->remarks = $remarks;
      $eventlog = new Eventlog();
      $eventlog->user_id = $current_user;
      $eventlog->mandate_id = $id;

      if($button_id == "reject"){
        $rejectreason_id = Input::get('rejectreason_id');
        $rejectreason = Input::get('rejectreason');
        $mandate->mandate_status = "Rejected";
        $mandate->rejectreason_id = $rejectreason_id;
        $eventlog->event = "Rejected: ".$rejectreason;
        //$this->generateXML($id,$rejectreason);   
      }else if($button_id == "verify") {
        $mandate->mandate_status = "Awaiting approval";
        $eventlog->event = "Verified";
      }
      else if($button_id == "approve") {
        $mandate->mandate_status = "Approved";
        $eventlog->event = "Approved";
        //$this->generateXML($id,$rejectreason);
      }

      $eventlog->save();
      $mandate->save();
    }
}
```

Now the error is gone but the code inside `if` statement is not working  now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$mandate = Mandate::find($id);
if(is_object($mandate)) {
  $mandate->user_id = $current_user;
  $mandate->remarks = $remarks;
}
```

Comment: The error is gone but the code inside 'if' statement not working. as given in EDIT1

Comment: @NithilGeorge: You have problem with "Mandate::find($id);" check Mandate class with find() is available or not. because of that $mandate is not initiating and it is not going inside if condition.